# SQL Server - Search Full Name Across First and Last Name Fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I'm assuming I will have user input that can be in one of 3 formats: "John", "John Doe", or "Doe".

Our latest version SQL Server database table Persons has FirstName and LastName columns.  As I don't really know if the user entered the fullname, only the last name, or only the first name as input, what is the best way to do a search and return records that are possible matches?  I'm thinking a FULLTEXT search, but not sure how that would look across the two columns, especially since each column could contain only part of the input as is the case when searching "John Doe".

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, with your given example of John Doe, the possibilities are (FirstName, LastName): `NULL, Doe` or `John, Doe` or `John, NULL`?

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the input and make them explicit on the application layer. If that isn't an option, a way (which would have false positives where FirstNames are the same as LastNames) would be similar to the below snippet. This assumes there would only be one space (if any) and is based off a lot of assumptions which will break depending on what a user inputs, hence my advice to handle this on the application layer.

```
declare @input varchar(256) = 'John Doe'

--if there is no space, then only a FirstName or LastName was supplied
if (select charindex(' ',@input)) = 0
begin
    select
        *
    from
        YourTable
    where
        FirstName = @input
        or
        LastName = @input
end

--if a space was found in input, we assume it was a FullName
else

begin
    select
        *
    from
        YourTable
    where
        FirstName = left(@input,charindex(' ',@input))
        and
        LastName = ltrim(right(@input,len(@input) - charindex(' ',@input)))
end
```

A more fuzzy way, would be with the `LIKE` clause.

```
select
   *
from
   YourTable
where
   FirstName + ' ' + LastName like + '%' + @input + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the variable with datatype table or Use temporary table,here i use temporary table,check this its working

declare @input_name varchar(100)

create table #name(name1 nvarchar(50),name2 nvarchar(50))

set @input_name = 'John'----('John', 'John Doe', 'Doe')

INSERT INTO #name SELECT  substring(@input_name, 1,charindex(' ',@input_name))  ,substring(@input_name, charindex(' ',@input_name),len(@input_name)-charindex(' ',@input_name)+1)
select * from #name

select * from Persons  where FirstName  =(select name1 from #name ) or LastName =(select name2 from #name ) or FirstName  =(select name2 from #name ) or LastName =(select name1 from #name )  

drop table #name
```

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of scenario, I prefer to add a CleanName column to the table. In your instance this would be the first name and last name columns combined into one with all non-alphanumeric characters removed so John Doe would be johndoe in the CleanName column. This is done as part of the query to add/update the data.

You can then just do a simple LIKE query to find your matches.

I prefer this method as some last names have non-alphanumeric characters, such as O'Reilly so this removes the need for the user to be completely accurate with spelling and format.

Answer (score -1):

Select * from table where (FirstName + LastName) like '%input%'